# Error "Cannot reduce the visibility of a inherited method" while implementing interface

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, subclass

I just installed the ta4j Technical Analysis lib .
It has a interface class called `TimeSeries`.
When I try to implement the first method in `TimeSeries`

`String getName()`

I get the following error:

> Cannot reduce the visabilty of a inhearted methed from TimeSeries
>   implaments org.ta4jcore.Timeserios.GetName

My Code

```
import org.ta4j.core.*;



public class cMyChartVal implements TimeSeries {
       /**
     * @return the name of the series
     */
    String getName()
    {
        return "TestSet";
    }
    .....
    .....
}
```

`TimeSeries` interface class

```
package org.ta4j.core;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Sequence of {@link Bar bars} separated by a predefined period (e.g. 15 minutes, 1 day, etc.)
 * </p>
 * Notably, a {@link TimeSeries time series} can be:
 * <ul>
 *     <li>the base of {@link Indicator indicator} calculations
 *     <li>constrained between begin and end indexes (e.g. for some backtesting cases)
 *     <li>limited to a fixed number of bars (e.g. for actual trading)
 * </ul>
 */
public interface TimeSeries extends Serializable {

    /**
     * @return the name of the series
     */
    String getName();

    /**
     * @param i an index
     * @return the bar at the i-th position
     */
    Bar getBar(int i);

    /**
     * @return the first bar of the series
     */
    default Bar getFirstBar() {
        return getBar(getBeginIndex());
    }

    /**
     * @return the last bar of the series
     */
    default Bar getLastBar() {
        return getBar(getEndIndex());
    }

    /**
     * @return the number of bars in the series
     */
    int getBarCount();

    /**
     * @return true if the series is empty, false otherwise
     */
    default boolean isEmpty() {
        return getBarCount() == 0;
    }

    /**
     * Warning: should be used carefully!
     * <p>
     * Returns the raw bar data.
     * It means that it returns the current List object used internally to store the {@link Bar bars}.
     * It may be:
     *   - a shortened bar list if a maximum bar count has been set
     *   - a extended bar list if it is a constrained time series
     * @return the raw bar data
     */
    List<Bar> getBarData();

    /**
     * @return the begin index of the series
     */
    int getBeginIndex();

    /**
     * @return the end index of the series
     */
    int getEndIndex();

    /**
     * @return the description of the series period (e.g. "from 12:00 21/01/2014 to 12:15 21/01/2014")
     */
    default String getSeriesPeriodDescription() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (!getBarData().isEmpty()) {
            Bar firstBar = getFirstBar();
            Bar lastBar = getLastBar();
            sb.append(firstBar.getEndTime().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME))
                    .append(" - ")
                    .append(lastBar.getEndTime().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the maximum number of bars that will be retained in the series.
     * <p>
     * If a new bar is added to the series such that the number of bars will exceed the maximum bar count,
     * then the FIRST bar in the series is automatically removed, ensuring that the maximum bar count is not exceeded.
     * @param maximumBarCount the maximum bar count
     */
    void setMaximumBarCount(int maximumBarCount);

    /**
     * @return the maximum number of bars
     */
    int getMaximumBarCount();

    /**
     * @return the number of removed bars
     */
    int getRemovedBarsCount();

    /**
     * Adds a bar at the end of the series.
     * <p>
     * Begin index set to 0 if if wasn't initialized.<br>
     * End index set to 0 if if wasn't initialized, or incremented if it matches the end of the series.<br>
     * Exceeding bars are removed.
     * @param bar the bar to be added
     * @see TimeSeries#setMaximumBarCount(int)
     */
    void addBar(Bar bar);

    /**
     * Returns a new TimeSeries implementation that is a subset of this TimeSeries implementation.
     * It holds a copy of all {@link Bar bars} between <tt>startIndex</tt> (inclusive) and <tt>endIndex</tt> (exclusive)
     * of this TimeSeries.
     * The indices of this TimeSeries and the new subset TimeSeries can be different. I. e. index 0 of the new TimeSeries will
     * be index <tt>startIndex</tt> of this TimeSeries.
     * If <tt>startIndex</tt> < this.seriesBeginIndex the new TimeSeries will start with the first available Bar of this TimeSeries.
     * If <tt>endIndex</tt> > this.seriesEndIndex the new TimeSeries will end at the last available Bar of this TimeSeries
     * @param startIndex the startIndex
     * @param endIndex the endIndex
     * @return a new BaseTimeSeries with Bars from startIndex to endIndex-1
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException e.g. if endIndex < startIndex
     */
    TimeSeries getSubSeries(int startIndex, int endIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All method declarations in an interface, including static methods, are implicitly public. And it's usually omitted.

The implementation class should keep this modifer, instead of using default class method modifer( `package level`).

You can change it to:

```
public String getName()
{
    return "TestSet";
}
```

Comment: Actually, all method in interfaces are implicitely public. Not really "default modifier" as this would imply that there are other non-default valid identifiers.